# SharpBITS.NET - rpc server is unavailable

Tags: c#, rpc, bit

Win Server 2008 R2 64bit + implemented as Windows service/C# (already updated to latest SharpBITS library).

This error occurs randomly - once in couple days. It makes all other calls to BITS manager object to fail => and windows service stops due BITS error event started. I did one workaround - wrapped call to the list Queue method with "try .. catch" and recreate BITS manager object "on error". But this hack-style solution only little bit improved stability - now service suddenly stops working without any error about once in a week.  :(

(Same code worked perfectly on Win Server 2003.)

SharpBITS library from: http://sharpbits.codeplex.com/

Comment: Monitor with [Debug Diagnostics Tool v1.2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960/en-us) and make analysis of dump.

Comment: Results from Debug Diagnostics Tool v1.2:

In DIBIST~3.DMP the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException+39 in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an unknown exception (0x800706be) on thread 9
Thread 9 - System ID 4288
Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
Create time   06.03.2013 11:49:47 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.125 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.62 
.NET Call Stack
Function 
SharpBits.Base.IBackgroundCopyJob.SetNotifyInterface(System.Object)

Comment: Submit error to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/)